# jetty-9 all the threads in TIMED_WAITING(parking) state

Tags: java, multithreading, jetty, spring-websocket, jetty-9

I have an application which which is deployed on jetty server.
Jetty standalone server has default configuration.Application contains spring based websocket.

Clients connect to the server using web-socket connection.
Once connection is established client sends heartbeat messages for every 5 seconds and sends few requests like requesting specific Data.

When client opens connection without sending any heart beat messages or specific requests am able to open any number of connections(tried upto 10000)

On the other hand,when all the threads are opened and started sending heart beat messages and specific requests parallely, server is hanged and is no longer able to accept connections greater than 2000.

Jetty Server version: jetty-distribution-9.3.8.v20160314

But after 2000 connections only application is getting hanged 
Using jstack took the thread dump and the following is the result:

"qtp1143839598-216" #216 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fcd88017000 nid=0x7365 waiting on condition [0x00007fcd344c3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000850d7fb0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(QueuedThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:609)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"qtp1143839598-215" #215 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fcd8c01c000 nid=0x7364 waiting on condition [0x00007fcd345c4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000850d7fb0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(QueuedThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:609)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"qtp1143839598-214" #214 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fcd805ea800 nid=0x735f waiting on condition [0x00007fcd346c5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000850d7fb0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(QueuedThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:609)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"qtp1143839598-213" #213 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fcd84135000 nid=0x7358 waiting on condition [0x00007fcd347c6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000850d7fb0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(QueuedThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:609)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"qtp1143839598-212" #212 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fcd78032000 nid=0x7354 waiting on condition [0x00007fcd348c7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000850d7fb0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(QueuedThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:609)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

There are around 196 threads with similar to the above logs

We are expecting 
 500K live connections at any point of time 2. 2000 new connections  per minute , 4000 re-connects (error and retry on client side)

Is there any way to configure jetty to handle the above requirement..and the above logs in jstack shows deadlock? or problem in application threads? Or is there any configuration to be made in spring websockets to achieve the above requirement. Sorry if language/framing of the question is not clear..

Comment: Ignore the `TIMED_WAITING` threads, those are just normal idle threads in the ThreadPool, waiting for something to use them.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt..What is the threads configuration of start.ini of jetty to handle 500000 websocket connections..In the above problem... after 2000 connections are established server is unable to accept more load..but in few posts i read i saw 200 threads(default) of jetty can handle upto 40000 active websocket connections